# Error using Beamer for Presentations in R Markdwon

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, miktex

I'm getting the below error when I try to knit any document into Beamer and I don't understand why. I have Miktex installed and updated.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerbasemodes.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.19 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

Answer (score 0):

With latex, if a .sty file isn't found, its because it isn't installed or MikTex doesn't know that its been installed and the FNDB must be refreshed.

I would check MikTex to verify that beamer is installed, and set the setting to install packages on the fly..

This tex.stachexchange answer might also lead to a solution.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404218/is-there-a-problem-with-beamer-in-the-latest-miktex-update